# Remember JS input for x mins in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to ask the user for their name and then remember that data for x mins. So if they come back to the page they aren't asked again?

Comment: Maybe you should look into [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: Is this part of a login/authentication system?

Comment: Similar too. I'd like to ask for the persons name and then say 'Hello name'. I've got that and it works. I want to store that name for x mins so they aren't asked again within x mins.

Answer (score 2):

I see two approaches here:

1. Cookies already support expiration. You might go this way then. Simply store a cookie with an expiration time and that's all.
2. You can store a key in `localStorage` and whenever the page is fully loaded, start a `setInterval` to check all `localStorage` keys with expiration. `localStorage` keys might use a naming convention like `expirable:[key name]` so you can iterate all keys and filter them by the whole convention. Inside each key you'll store a JSON with your data and an arbitrary property called `expires` which might be the date on which the key was store to later compare it with *current date* overtime with `setInterval` and delete the key if it has already expired...

Comment: And how would I do this? I'm new to JS and Cookies. I've learned HTML and CSS and know most of that. Cheers.

Comment: @tropilac oops this goes out of the scope of a Q&A... Now you need to do your own investigation and come again with specific questions. This is how SO works...

Comment: @Tropilac Matias has given you 2 good starting points. We are not going to write an entire solution for you. Go do some research, work out which best fits your needs as that is something only you can do. Attempt to write some code. If you have problems with that code come and ask for some help with that.

Comment: Okay, I'm asking what local storage is? How do I get it? Do I need a web server??? How do I set a cookie??

Comment: @Tropilac, research, use google/bing etc. Here is a link to get you started:  https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/